# Generate and attach X509 certificate to an Amazon ec2 account

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

Amazon's documentation seems to assume that everyone using it knows all about X509 certificates and exactly how to generate them.  I don't, and no one on the internet seems to be interested in explaining how to do the minimum to generate an X509 certificate that works with EC2.  What, exactly and in very specific steps, is necessary to generate an X509 certificate that works with EC2? The target environment for these steps is Ubuntu 12.04.

*Edit: Note that I cannot simply use the 'Generate X509 certificate' tab, because this is an IAM account.*

Comment: Google: HowTo: Generate an X.509 Certificate for  Amazon

Comment: This link might help: [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-credentials.html#using-credentials-certificate)

Comment: @hek2mgl - I have been, and have gotten nothing specific to EC2.  I've gotten several results that are more complicated than doing my taxes by hand, and I can't believe it's actually that hard.  John, see my edit - I can't do that.

Comment: I found this [link](http://www.dowdandassociates.com/content/howto-generate-x509-certificate-amazon-iam-user). I hope this helps